# Need to write a regex in typescript for a string starting with "abcd_" and allowing only alphanumeric chars and underscore

Tags: javascript, typescript

"abcd_" shouldn't be immediately followed by another underscore. Upon searching I found the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` for allowing only alphanumeric chars and underscore.
I am finding difficulty to combine two or more conditions.To check the start string pattern was simple as-

```
static myValidator(control) {
    if(control.value) {
        if(control.value.match(/^abcd_/)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return {'invalidName':true};
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Update with some sample input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

`^abcd_([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?$` if `abcd_` is already valid by itself and nothing needs to follow.

Otherwise `^abcd_[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$` requires at least one character after `abcd_`.

Or if there need to be at least 6 characters after `abcd_`: `^abcd_[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,}$`

Answer (score 0):

A regex typically reads left to right. In order to combine rules, just make sure you order them correctly. For instance checking `/^abcd_/` will literally look for the substring `abcd_` at the start of the string. To make sure the next symbol is alphanumeric but not an underscore, we might do `/^abcd_[^_\W]/` which basically reads as "not an underscore and not, not an alphanumeric" since `\W` is equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`. Lastly we check for zero or more alphanumeric characters with `\w*$`, note that this w is lowercase and is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, and the * means 0 or more of the preceeding subexpression and the $ makes it non-greedy.

So we end up with a final regex of:

`/^abcd_[^_\W]\w*$/i`

Depending on exactly what you want to be able to match (hard to tell without any expected output) then it may need to be modified.

Check this link for example matches and a more in-depth explanation of what the regex does.

https://regex101.com/r/fzKhIx/3

I would also recommend reading this guide on regular expressions in javascript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions